# Which verb tense do I use for a secondary but perpetual action mentioned in a sentence that happened in the past?

Tags: tenses, indirect-speech, backshifting, narration

I’m trying to write a sentence in which the primary action occurred in the
past, but within that sentence is another subject–verb pair in which the
verb describes a perpetual state of being.

Here is my original sentence, which recounts a time when I was getting
familiar with Christianity as a child:

1. I **had** no idea what a savior **is**.

Here *savior is* is the subject–verb pair in question. It sounds funny to me,
but it seems grammatically correct. I’m not sure though.

I tried the following variation:

2. I **had** no idea what “savior” **means**.

Again, I feel like this is correct, but with *had* as past tense and
*means* as present tense, they sound off in the same sentence.

If I change
*is* and *means* to past tense *are* and *meant*, they sound better in my head.

3. I **had** no idea what a savior **was**.
4. I **had** no idea what “savior” **meant**.

But the word *savior* **will** always have a definition, and the concept of a
savior **will** always exist.

So the *is/means* verbs “should” be in present tense, shouldn’t they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. You are describing your past perception of something that you believe is defined for all time.

Let us assume for the purpose of argument that *savior* had, has and always will have a permanent definition. (The assumption is of course questionable, for who can foresee the future?)

Because of that permanency "*what that {permanent  definition} was*" is perfectly synonymous with "*what that {permanent  definition} is*".

Is there any difference in the usage? If you use "*savior was*", you direct the reader's attention to your perception at that past time when you considered a savior; you also leave open the possibility that the definition may change in future. If you use "*savior is*", you focus slightly more on the permanency of the meaning of savior. But, given the synonymity, these are trivial and arguable differences, and you may use either construct.

Answer (score 1):

The more correct usage would be

I had no idea what a savior *was*.

and

I had no idea what "savior" *meant*.

In each case they are sticking with the description of the past condition. They may change later in your description but until the present description comes around it is all past perfect.

Comment: I think "correct" is ungradeable, and your first sentence should be the more positive: *"The correct use is ..."* It is clear that the writer **did not know** (simple past) *then* but knows *now*.